# How to check if a session variable exists

Tags: magento-1.9, session

How we can check if a session variable exists in Mangento. I know how to create a new variable.

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyValue($myValue);
```

My aim is to check if session variable MyValue exists. If exists do nothing otherwise create one

Comment: did I manage to answer your question ? If so could you please mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyValue())
{
    // Value exists, do stuff
}
else
{
    // Value does not exists, do other stuff
}
```